# unchecked call to push(E) as a member of the raw type Stack

Tags: java, vector, stack

First of all this code does run fine. But, I've seen the problem regarding an unchecked call to push(E) because of a raw type quite a few times so far on stack overflow and the common solution has been to declare my stack as so

```
    Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

but I'm doing so and still getting the same problem. Here is a small example to show what is happening but I can't seem to get rid of the error:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

static void myPush (Stack myStack, int b){
    myStack.push(new Integer(b));
    System.out.println("inserted element is: " + b);
    System.out.println("this is on the stack: " + myStack);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    myPush(myStack, 10);
    myPush(myStack, 12);
    myPush(myStack, 13);
}

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Side note: `myStack.push(b)` is usually preferable to `myStack.push(new Integer(b))`.

Answer (score 7):

You are using a raw type in the method declaration. Change,

```
static void myPush (Stack myStack, int b)
```

to

```
static void myPush (Stack<Integer> myStack, int b)
```

**Alternatively,** make the method generic on *type* `T` like

```
static <T> void myPush(Stack<T> myStack, T b) {
    myStack.push(b);
    System.out.println("inserted element is: " + b);
    System.out.println("this is on the stack: " + myStack);
}
```

**Finally,** Java 7 introduced the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) `<>` which you can use to change

```
Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();
```

to

```
Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what it was

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs perfectly fine. Regarding the existence of a warning, (which is what I assume you're worried about) it's because you're again declaring a raw type as your parameter. `myStack` should actually be declared as

```
...Stack<Integer> myStack...
```